# Is it possible to reduce the retry period of 7 days of a firebase function to a lesser value?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

[This documentation page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries) describes how to enable retries for asynchronous firebase functions. It mentions the maximum retry period is 7 days.

> Cloud Functions guarantees at-least-once execution of an event-driven
> function for each event emitted by an event source. However, by
> default, if a function invocation terminates with an error, the
> function will not be invoked again, and the event will be dropped.
> When you enable retries on an event-driven function, Cloud Functions
> will retry a failed function invocation until it completes
> successfully or the retry window expires (by default, after 7 days).

Is there a way to reduce the retry period to few minutes, from the default value of 7 days?

Comment: Unfortunately, the default Firebase Functions retry period of 7 days cannot be shortened to a few minutes. The longest possible retry period is specified by Google Cloud Functions and is 7 days. Making a new function that is activated by a timer could be a workaround to change the default Firebase Functions retry period from 7 days to a few minutes. This timer-triggered function can be used to monitor the performance of the original function and, if necessary, attempt it at predetermined intervals.

Comment: Does this answer your question? I will post it as an answer if yes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Posting my comment as an answer:**

"Unfortunately, the default Firebase Functions retry period of 7 days cannot be shortened to a few minutes. The longest possible retry period is specified by Google Cloud Functions and is 7 days. Making a new function that is activated by a timer could be a workaround to change the default Firebase Functions retry period from 7 days to a few minutes. This timer-triggered function can be used to monitor the performance of the original function and, if necessary, attempt it at predetermined intervals."